# Is there any API for getting all countries and passing country get all States/Region and again passing State/Region get all cities in it

Tags: location, state, region, country, city

I am creating a web page in asp.net where I have to populate all countries in a dropdown. On selecting one country I need to populate all States/Region in that country to another dropdown. finally on selecting the state/region need to populate all cities in that state/region into another dropdown. is there any api for achieving this. Can any one please help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://www.geonames.org/export/web-services.html

http://api.shopify.com/country.html

http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21locale.inc/function/country_get_list/7

You might have to call multiple API's to achieve this. Hope this helps.